# git config user.name gives wrong user name

Tags: git

I started using git on the command line. And am trying to configure user name.

For example, inside my git repository directory, I ran

```
git config --global user.name lzeng
```

However, running "git config user.name" gives "defaultuser". But I just set it to "lzeng". How can that be?

Comment: Hi PetSerAI, after running "git config user.name --list --show-origin", I see that user.name is set to "--list"

Comment: @user128177 He may have meant `git config --list --show-origin`, which should list all your config items along with their originating files. Do you see `user.name` multiple times in the output?

Comment: yes. Running "git config user.name lzeng " fixed it. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But I just set it to `lzeng`. How can that be?

Running `git config --global user.name lzeng` sets `user.name` to `lzeng` **at global level**. Try running `git config user.name lzeng`. It will set the variable at **local/repository level**. Then when you run `git config user.name`, it should return `lzeng`.

If you run `git config --list --show-origin`, you should see `user.name` defined twice. The last of those definitions will take effect. Chances are that `user.name` is somehow set to `defaultuser` **at local level** (check your `.git/config` file).

---

Reference: [1.6 Getting Started - First-Time Git Setup](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup)

Answer (score 0):

Use this file as a point of reference. The syntax for the config file is not the same as the commands for the terminal.

https://gist.github.com/pksunkara/988716

Comment: An example config file won't help much in solving the original problem. While its generally a good idea to quote and link to authorative information (e..g the actual git documentation), please make sure to tailor the quoted information to the actual question.